# Android app crashing on different devices

Tags: android, android-studio

I am building an app for a client, its about 90% done and he wanted to test it out along with a few of his friends. One of his friends came up with an issue were the app is crashing on his device but it works on everyone else's devices. Now I have four personal android devices I try my apps on and am not facing the problem on any of them. It's remote work so I can't get his device to figure out what's going on. How do people handle apps behaving differently on other devices and how can this be avoided.

Comment: One option is to create an emulator that matches the other guy's device. Maybe you can recreate with that. Otherwise, you will need to get the exact same device. If this is for a client, ask them to buy it for you if they want you to fix it.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice what is the best way to figure out the emulator that matches it? Its an infinix phone, its not the most popular brand

Comment: Get the specs from your client. The most important is what version of Android the phone uses.

Comment: You might also want to explain to your client that it isn't a commonly used phone. So it isn't worth the time to fix an issue that is specific to that phone model.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Alright thanks I really appreciate it

Comment: Start by adding logic to your app to collect crash information and make it available to you. There are commercial services for this (Sentry, Firebase Crashlytics, etc.) and open source code (e.g., [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra)) as well. Ask this person to run the app to the point of the crash. Eventually, you will get access to the stack trace and other information related to the crash. From there, you can either devise a fix or come back here (or other developer support points) with the stack trace and a [mcve] to get assistance.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you so much I really appreciate that I literally had no clue thank you